# Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Unable to execute runtime binding on null reference'

Tags: c#, wpf, api

I get movie API from OMDB API and I want to assign data in API to strings.

**Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Unable to execute runtime binding on null reference'**
But I am getting this error. What could be the solution?

```cs
public MainViewModel()
{
    SearchCommand = new RelayCommand((e) =>
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        var name = SearchText;
        response = http.GetAsync($@"http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=a91a5037&t={name}&plot=full").Result;
        var str = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
        MoviePosterPath = Data.Search[0].Poster; // I'm getting errors here
        MovieTitle = Data.Search[0].Title;
        MovieIMDB = Data.Search[0].imdbRating;
        MovieYear = Data.Search[0].Released;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.omdbapi.com/) you want to get details by `Search`. In that case the parameter in the url should by `s` not `t`.

```
response = http.GetAsync($@"http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=a91a5037&s={name}&plot=full").Result;
```

The rest of your code can remain unchanged.